# Question about supposed Tosfos

Tags: tosfot

In "The Path of the Torah," the English translation of the Netziv's introduction to Ha'amek Sheila, on page 132, the translator writes in the footnote there, "The Netziv may be directing this argument against the Tosafos s.v. Man de-hu, in Tractate Ta’anis 15a, that states that the narratives in the Books of the prophets are not divrei kabbalah, words received through Divine inspiration or conveyed from Moses at Sinai. The responsa of the Havos Da’as, siman 9, claims that this Tosafos was written in “great error” by a student of the Ba’alei ha-Tosafos, the Tosafists."  First of all, there is no such Tosafos on Ta'anis 15a.  Is there such a Tosafos anywhere in Shas?  Secondly, does anyone know which "Havos Da'as siman 9" he is referring to?

Comment: It's from Rashi: https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Taanit.15a.5.2

Comment: @shmosel yes i actually figured that out a few minutes before you posted that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind.  Apparently the translator of the work was incorrect.   There is no such Tosfos.  There is, however, an unspecified Tosafos printed in Rashi to Ta'anis 15a, as noted there by Artscroll Talmud.  And the translator further erred by quoting "Havos Da'as, siman 9," when it actually should be Chavos Yair responsum 9, again quoting Artscroll Talmud.

Comment: @shmosel can you tell me where in Chavos Yair 9 he refers to it

Comment: @shmosel  can you translate the Chavos Yair where he writes "מה שהגיה תלמיד טועה ברש"י ר"פ סדר תעניות הוא שיבוש גדול מאוד שהש"ס אומר בכמה דוכתי ד"ת מד"ק לא ילפינן אף שאין ענין לתוכחה ומוסר ע' ריש ב"ק ובמסכת נדה פ"ג דכ"ג חגיגה דף י'

Comment: "That which a mistaken student edited into Rashi in Taanis is a very great error, for the gemara says in many places 'we don't learn divrei torah from divrei kabbalah', even where it doesn't pertain to matters of rebuke."

Comment: @shmosel thanks man